# Google maps v3 infobox zIndex not functional

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a map and an marker on it. When i click on the marker a pop up (infobox.js) apeares that have this properties (pane: "floatPane" and zIndex: 1) and my Marker has zIndex 2. When i click on the marker the pop up apeares uppon the marker even if it has the zIndex smaller. I know that if i set pane to mapPane it will be under, but i need it to floatPane to be uppon other markers that are on the map. Why the zIndex its no working? I've put some alerts with the zIndex to be sure that they are like i think and they are.

Answer (score 5):

The zIndex property is only useful  between objects that are on the same pane. The floatPane, is above all overlays, as stated in the [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes):

> **floatPane** (Node)  This pane contains the info window. It is above all map
>   overlays. (Pane 6).

Markers are overlays and they are held on:

> **overlayImage**  (Node)  This pane contains the marker foreground images.
>   (Pane 3).

Comment: i know this, but is there a way to put the infobox and the markers into the same Pane? because i've set the infobox pane to : overlayImage and it still dont works

Comment: Thanks! This helped me - my infoBox was on `mapPane` by default - changing it to `floatPlane` put it above all markers.